# JSTL custom tag variable substitution

Tags: jsp, jstl

What am I doing wrong here:

```
<custom:tag param="<c:out value="${param.val}"/>" >
...
</custom:tag>
```

I keep getting

```
test.jsp:6: expected `>' at ``$'' (for tag `<custom:tag>' at line 6).  The XML tag syntax is: <tag attr1='value1'>
```

But this is fine:

```
<a href="<c:out value="${param.val}"/>">link</a>
```

Obviously I want to avoid

```
<custom:tag param="<%= request.getParameter("val") %>" />
```

Doing it without the `c:out` doesn't work either, my jstl doesn't know about `<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>`

### Excerpt from tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
<taglib>
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
  <short-name>...</short-name>
  <uri>...</uri>

  <tag>
       <name>...</name>
       <tag-class>...</tag-class>
       <description>...</description>
       <attribute>
         <name>attr1</name>
         <required>true</required>
       </attribute>
       <attribute>
         <name>param</name>
         <required>true</required>
         <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
       </attribute>
  </tag>
</taglib>
```

Comment: See my last sentence in the question.  It won't be replaced at all. I just tried again after your comment.  Same result, I get a literal `${param.val}` in the custom tag.

Comment: `<custom:tag ... />` was a typo, see updated question. What doesn't work is that I get a literal `${param.val}` and not its value.

Comment: Can you post your tld? Are you specifying `<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>` for you param attribute?

Comment: Well, the whole thing is way too long. `<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>` is set though.  Anything else?

Comment: Just post the relevant tag... it should not be more than 10-15 lines unless you have many many attributes. Without more concrete details it's just a guessing game.

Comment: JSP 1.2? Really? JSP 1.x died more than 10 years ago. Which servletcontainer are you deploying to? Tomcat 4.1.x or so?

Comment: According to your TLD, you are missing the required attr1 attribute...

Comment: Well, Resin/2.1.17 Can't change, don't ask.  So is it old JSP/JSTL standard?

Comment: The missing `attr1` attribute is not the problem, it is added in the actual call.  Maybe I should have added that the scriptlet version does work (the one I noted I want to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

Hey why are you adding

```
<c:out value="${param.val}"/>
```

in param

```
<custom:tag param="<c:out value="${param.val}"/>" >
...
</custom:tag>
```

you just need to add

```
${param.val}
```

in param like below 
    
        ...

Answer (score 0):

A section of [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahr.html) (there might be a later version somewhere) explains about the EL:

> All expressions using the ${} syntax are evaluated immediately. These expressions can be used only **within template text** or **as the value of a tag attribute that can accept runtime expressions**.

In the question, in the error case it is neither of those:

```
<custom:tag param="<c:out value="${param.val}"/>">
                  ^             ^^          ^^  ^
                  1             23          45  6
```

In parsing the custom tag, there's delimited tag value at 1-2, then the surprising EL at 3-4. The apparent delimited string at 5-6 is irrelevant at this point but also not correct syntax. To be inside the attribute value, the EL would need to be inside the quotes that delimit the value, but it is *beside* the value.

(The error message

```
test.jsp:6: expected `>' at ``$'' (for tag `<custom:tag>' at line 6).  The XML tag syntax is: <tag attr1='value1'>
```

is saying it's expecting the tag to be closed with `>` but a `$` was encountered. It's difficult to know for sure what the intended outcome is, but if the solution needs to use c:out to format the value, you could split it into two, like

```
<c:set var="paramVal"><c:out value="${param.val}"/></c:set>
<custom:tag param="${paramVal}"/>
...
</custom:tag>
```

though you'd also possibly need to add escapeXml="false" to the c:out tag.)

In the second case,

```
<a href="<c:out value="${param.val}"/>">link</a>
        ^^            ^^          ^^ ^^
        12            34          56 78
```

the quotes at 1 and 8 are in the template text, so they're not delimiting anything. The c:out tag is at 2-7 containing the value of the value attribute at 3-6, which contains the EL at 4-5, so it's valid JSP.

Answer (score -2):

Try using.

```
<custom:tag param="<c:out value='${param.val}'/>" >
   ...
</custom:tag>
```

This will simply fix the syntax so you don't get the error message that you posted at the top. 
Using EL should work. EL was originally part of JSTL.
What does just a simple tag(no custom tag) like

```
<c:out value='${"Hello JSTL"}'/>
```

Print?

Comment: Thanks, actually tried that before.  Yields `${param.val}` again, i.e., no substitution.

Comment: All shoot-in-the-dark "answers" in the line of "try this" wherein you're completely unable to concretely and constructively explain the cause *and* the solution in clear technical terms like this should be posted as comments.

Comment: BasusC, I simply fixed the double quote problem. I think everybody can see that. It doesn't need any explanation. After he fixed that, he didn't get the error message that he posted at the top.